# Dynamic LINQ join on runtime specified entities. Need filterable returned object. Possible?

Tags: c#, .net, linq, .net-core, entity-framework-core

I'm attempting to figure out the Possibility of dynamically joining entities. The specific entities are unknown at compile time.

Case:

- During the application a user can request any entities with relations
  to eachother to be joined and receive a table with the data. This table 
  be filterable afterwards.

These entities are defined with Entity Framework Core.

Target framework is the latest .NET Core (Currently 2.1) with the latest Entity Framework Core (Currently 2.1).

**A couple restrictions:**

- After this it is **very** important that the resulting object is still
  queryable with LINQ Where filters.
- Everything must be loaded Lazily.
- At least able to do BOTH inner join AND outer left join.

I can find very little information about this and if I find something it's often around 10 years old and unknown if those features are in EFCore.

Comment: Look for Dynamic Linq... There are various versions on Nuget... not sure if they are compatible with .NET Core. [This one](https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Linq.Dynamic.Core/) says *This is a .NETStandard/ .NET Core port of the the Microsoft assembly for the .Net 4.0 Dynamic language functionality.*

Comment: @xanatos I'm currently reading their documentation. Sadly hard to understand for me and most of it is autogenerated. If I'm reading it correctly, with their joins one of the 'sequences' needs to be an IEnumerable, specifically the 'Inner sequence'. This would be a dealbreaker already.

Comment: If you take a look at the "default" `Queryable.Join` you'll see that the joined table is a `IEnumerable<>`... There is some magic somewhere that makes it work as a `IQueryable` joined to a `IQueryable`. But the signature doesn't show this magic. I'll say that there is a 50% possibility that this magic is present even in the dynamic library. You can check it by using a profiler on your sql server

Comment: @xanatos Weird, thanks. I guess the only option is trying that out.